# iOS NFC Background Tag Reading Without User Input

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

I understand that iOS now allows for NFC tag reading in the background. However, it states that the user must always tap on a notification before the app will receive the NFC data. I get that there is a good reason to default to this behavior, but is there any way to avoid this?

The app I'm developing at work needs NFC to work in the background without user input. Are there any background execution modes or something that we could use to avoid this limitation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. You can not change this behaviour. It is built into the operating system itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solution. The Automations tab in the Shortcuts app can handle background tag reading without user interaction, however, it does not read the contents of the tag, besides the ID. When it detects a tag that has been registered before, it will run the action attached to that.

For security, there is no other way to allow an app to react to a tag read in the background, without a user tapping on the notification, and that notification being for a URL record that opens the app or performs another URL-based operation.

Comment: What about in the foreground? Can an app, designed to read NFC tags, read multiple tags successively without user interaction when the app is open?

Comment: Yes, but the user has to start the session and it will still have a 60-second timeout. If they start the session, you can choose whether to allow multiple reads or not

Comment: That's a pain for the user experience. I really hope they remove this limitation eventually.

Comment: File a radar or send a message to Apple if you think they should change something. I think for most scenarios this is acceptable

Comment: Done. Use cases could include inventory management, time and attendance, visitor sign in kiosks, process tracking. These kinds of apps should be able to scan NDEF-formated NFC tags while the app is open, without restrictions.